# MissingMethodException MapInheritedProperties when I try to generate the views

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Can someone suggest what I might be doing wrong here. Seems like it's a minor thing that I am not seeing as I have done the same thing before in different projects:

EFRepository.cs:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Configurations
            ...
            .Add(new TransferredStreamConfiguration())
            ...
    ;
}
```

TransferTargetConfiguration.cs:

```
class TransferredStreamConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<TransferredStream>
{
    public TransferredStreamConfiguration()
    {
        Map(p =>
            {
                p.MapInheritedProperties();
                p.ToTable("TransferredStream");
            })
            ;

        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
            .HasColumnOrder(0)
            ;

        ...
    }
}
```

TransferredStream.cs

```
public partial class TransferredStream : Entity
{
    public virtual string StoreName { get; set; }
    ...
}

public abstract partial class Entity : IEquatable<Entity>, IValidatable
{
    public virtual long Id { get; protected internal set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I saw a bunch of comments about this and similar problems with the tool. They all seem to have something to do with another component loading different version of EF in VS... and thought that we are out of the dll hell... Anyway, I uninstalled VSCommands and still cannot solve my problem. Can someone please help: I am on VS2013 ultimate with EF 6.2 and power tools installed... Is it possible that the EF Power Tools extension is incompatible with EF 6.2?

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case:

Entity Framework is installed as a NuGet package on all my projects that have to work with my Data class library (project).
I had recently updated my Data project with the latest Entity Framework version. But because I hadn't done this on my Test Project, it was taking the dll that this project was referencing instead of the updated one of my Data project.

So to summarize:

**Check each project in your solution for NuGet updates and perform them.**